# 32bit java на 64bit debian linux

Tags: java, linux, debian

Есть 64bit debian-подобный linux и заменен/изменен быть не может (в том числе нельзя устанавливать пакеты, которые заменят существующие). Есть какая-то crmXXX, в которой можно открывать задачи, письма и прочее. Если через эту crmXXX открывать файл, то используется java-апплет.
Проблема в том, что crmXXX работает с 32 битной java.
Как установить в 64bit debian linux 32bit java?

Comment: Хотите сказать, что crm не запускается на 64-битной jvm?

Comment: сделать можно, но лучше послать это crmXXX подальше. Это правильное решение. Костыль выглядит так. Скачивается 32битный фаерфокс (не с репозитория), у него отключается обновление и скачивается отдельно нужная жава. Все это настраиваетс в отдельной папке. Версию жавы и фаерфокса придется подганять. После обновления фаерфокс часто решает, что жава "небезопасна" и блокирует ее. Всю эту конфигурацию запихаем в отдельный батник и используем к доступу к crmXXX (кстати, а что же это за вредитель?)

Comment: была такая идея, но это же сколько всего еще придется притащить чтобы запустился firefox. Еще думал через docker запустить, но он не работает в том linux, придется кое что отключить, чего отключить нельзя

Comment: я так делал, потому что использовалась программа для миттингов от циски. В конце концов ее выбросили, потому что оно даже под виндой не заводилось нормально.

Comment: вроде как достиг определенного результата использовав IBM Java, про нее писали, что она "умеет 32bit". Во всяком случае crmXXX больше не показывает ошибку wrong elf class, а упирается в какие-то права. И очень похоже, что упирается сам плагин. Но это уже оставлю на совести разработчиков той crm.

Answer (score 4):

```sh
# Добавляем поддержку 32 бит
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
# Обновляем список пакетов
sudo apt update
# Устанавливаем 32-битную версию пакета
sudo apt install default-jre:i386
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но проблема намного глубже

Comment: @SebastianPereiro, вам дан абсолютно правильный ответ на вопрос «как установить …?». если это не решает какую-то иную стоящую перед вами проблему, то задайте, пожалуйста, по этому поводу **новый** вопрос (с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы).

Comment: Немного исправил условие, для понимания сути. Так-то ответ верный, но, к сожалению, абсолютно бесполезный.

Comment: @SebastianPereiro, кстати, фактически ответ соответствует дополнительно выдвинутым вами условиям: будут установлены сборки **абсолютно тех же самых** пакетов, только собранных под другую архитектуру.

Comment: Да, если говорить о чистом Debian